# If I get a lot of sensitive data using 'get_defined_vars()' - is this a security breach? Can any user request these variables in any way?

Tags: php, security

I am working on a 10 year old PHP website, not running on any framework. Just flat PHP scripts (the old fashioned way, including/requiring other files).

I have been looking for a variable to complete a code I'm writing using the function: [get_defined_vars()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) - and noticed there are tons of variables that are outputted on the page, with user names, passwords and a lot more data like databases credentials etc.

Is there any way a user can get this data printed/echoed/var_dumped/request? 
or is this obligated that only I, the one with access to the PHP files - from within the server, to use then however I want and not display them to a user, willingly or unwillingly?

Comment: Its safe as long as you have no security vulnerability in the app which allow RFI/LFI or arbitrary code executions. If its not then an attacker would drop a backdoor on the server and just directly access the config files and not bother escalating via that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this function for debugging only. I can not think of any good reason to use it in live code.

> Is there any way a user can get this data
>   printed/echoed/var_dumped/request?

Not without access to your PHP files or some breach.

> If I get a lot of sensetive data using 'get_defined_vars()' - is this
>   a security breach? (user names, passwords and a lot more data like databases credentials etc.)

*Not necessarily a breach*. But maybe easy to intrude if there is a breach somewhere.

I think this old code could need a lot of work if you want to improve security:

- Encrypted Passwords should never be in the public variable scope
- Plain Text passwords should never be anywhere and should not exist in any application - this would be a total fail even in 10 year old code
- Encapsulate your components (user, database) if you have the time for that
- Have save settings within your php.ini and update PHP to the latest version (have fun with fixing 10 year old code for that :-D ). Here is a nice tutorial for improving PHP security: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html